# Write logs to Android logcat without using standard apis

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

I want to implement __android_log_write() functionality using write() or some api available in libc(actually ulibc). The reason being that i cannot use any libraries associated with android as that would increase the memory required. I have very limited amount of memory as my code is running in separate memory region reserved during boot up. Main goal is to attach my debugging logs to logcat.

I am looking something similar to this:

```
write(1,"sandy",6);
```

The abovce code i can directly write to stdout. Similarly, i want to use write() or something else and write to logcat. What is the clean way to do it.

Hope i am clear. Thanks.

Comment: While it's not Android related, this [post by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx) is appropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. We need to open /dev/radio and write into them.

Thanks